# How can I export upscaled images from Lightroom with each pixel just a large square block?

Tags: lightroom, anti-aliasing

I want to be able to export an image from Lightroom at a higher pixel count than the original— that is, instead of each pixel of the image being one pixel by one pixel, they are, say ten by ten pixels.  What I don't want is for the pixels to be smoothed into each other/anti aliased.

I tried exporting the image from Lightroom and specifying the desired width at a higher pixel count than the original, but it automatically anti-aliased the image.

Is what I'm asking possible?

Comment: Can you explain why you want this?

Comment: Are you okay with using a tool other than Lightroom to do the upscaling?

Comment: Your desired sampling mode is rarely used for photographic purposes. Try a general purpose image manipulation tool instead.

Answer (score 2):

Anti-aliasing is a technique used to make shapes and lines appear less jagged in pixel based graphics. Anti-aliasing is only a part of some of the algorithms that Lightroom and other professional applications deploy when upscaling images. Considering the fact that you are really trying to generate (passable) information that wasn't there in the first place, there are limitations to upscaling images.

Lightroom doesn't have the same advanced algorithms that other applications dedicated solely to upscaling images have, so you will get better results if you upscale to a multiple of the original width and height; 200%, 400% etc. Photoshop will allow you to pick between a handful of different resampling algorithms, but Lightroom will intelligently pick behind the scenes.

If you are looking for a better implementation of upscaling, that is a question that has been asked before:

- [Best software for upsampling to about 2x?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76054/best-software-for-upsampling-to-about-2x)
- [How can I upscale a low-res image to make it appear higher-res?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18468/how-can-i-upscale-a-low-res-image-to-make-it-appear-higher-res)
- [How to scale up a photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29854/how-to-scale-up-a-photo)

If you want to preserve the pixels when upscaling, as *mattdm* suggests might be the case, that is possible in Photoshop with the resampling algorithm; Nearest neighbor. I haven't found any results online to suggest the same is possible with Lightroom, which makes sense because such a feature would add nothing for photographers. If you have access to Photoshop, this tutorial explains:

- http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/39976/photoshop-scale-pixel-art-without-losing-quality/

Comment: It sounds like margalo wants a *worse* implementation, not a better one, for some reason.

Comment: I didn't even think of that. I've updated my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to export and resize it in some other software.

Gimp can resize with no pixel interpolation:

https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-scale.html

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial using [ImageMagick's `scale` option](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#scale). Assuming your original image (exported from Lightroom) is `original.gif`, and your upscaled output image will be `upscaled.gif`, then,

```
convert original.gif -scale 1000% upscaled.gif
```

will produce an image that is 10× larger in each dimension, effectively "blowing up" the 1×1 pixels in the original image to 10×10.

Important: make sure the `scale` percentage is a multiple of 100%, otherwise pixel interpolation *will* occur.